# How to set sender email Id while using Flask Mail

Tags: python, flask, smtp, flask-mail

I am using Flak Mail to send email from a website's contact form. Contact form has a `sender` email id field as well. So when I receive the email at "recipient" email id I want `from` to be set as `sender` email Id to have the value entered on the form. Following is the class that handles emails:

```
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

class SendMail:

    def __init__(self, app):
        app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
        app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
        app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'smtpsetup@gmail.com'
        app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = '<password>'
        app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
        app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
        self.recipient_email = 'recipient@gmail.com'
        self.app = app
        self.mail = Mail(self.app)

    def compile_mail(self, name, email_id, phone_no, msg):
        message = Message(name+" has a query",
                          sender = email_id,
                          recipients=[self.recipient_email])
        message.html = "<b>Name : </b>"+name+"<br><b>Phone No :</b> "+phone_no+"<br><b>Message : </b>"+msg
        return message

    def send_mail(self, name, email_id, phone_no, msg):
        message = self.compile_mail(name, email_id, phone_no, msg)
        with self.app.app_context():
            self.mail.send(message)
```

`send_mail` method receives four arguments which are the fields entered on the contact form. The problem is, when I send email like this, the `from` in the email received is set to the SMTP MAIL_USERNAME `smtpsetup@gmail.com`, despite the fact that I am setting `sender` parameter in Message object as `email_id` received from the contact form. 
Not able to figure out how to set sender to a value i want.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @TylerDavidson I couldn't find a solution instead a work around. I started using SendGrid API to send emails. Now I am able to set "from" correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that the `email_id` you are passing in is what you think it is?

[The Flask Mail source code](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail/blob/master/flask_mail.py#L275) suggests that it will only use the default if the `sender` you pass in is falsy (e.g. None or an empty string).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to set the sender name to something than is not an email address(like sender = "Stackoverflow"), you can set the sender arguement  as a tuple.

```
message = Message(name+" has a query",
                  sender = (email_id, app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"]),
                  # 'email_id' will replace 'app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"]' as the name that shows up in your email
                  recipients=[self.recipient_email])
```

Comment: this win and helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your mail configuration:

MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER : default
None(replace with the email you wish to be the sender). E.g

app.config["MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER"] = "myemail@gmail.com"